# How to animate tab content using jquery tabs()

Tags: jquery, tabs, effects, fade

so far I have the following:

```
$("ul.search-tabs").tabs("div.panes > div");
```

How can I make the content of each tab appears/disappear with a fadeIn/Out effect?

Thanks!!!

Comment: You mean when you switch tabs, or when you click some other button on the page?

Comment: when I switch tabs... I want the div containing the info for the selected tab to fadeIn instead of just showing up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this when initalize:

```
$("ul.search-tabs").tabs(fx:{opacity:'fadein'});
```

see the JQuery-ui doc [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#option-fx).

Comment: i think you dont need your `$("ul.search-tabs").tabs("div.panes > div");` line if you name your divs correctly (with the corresponding tab's href property as id)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$( "#ul.search-tabs" ).tabs({ fx: { opacity: 'toggle' } });
```

Comment: This is an option, should be supplied with tabs call. For more info see http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#option-fx in options fx.